# How to add google maps to flutter app which works also on web platform and still work in each platform?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

I recently add web support to my app , but the problem was google maps ,
I'm using flutter_google_maps fro android and IOS but for web , I Had some problems :
I used google_map plugin for web and it worked for web , but when I try to run the project on mobile an error show up that "dart:html" is not found .
I searched for the error , I found the universal_html library which also did't work for me .

this is my code :

```
// import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;


class GoogleMap extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String htmlId = "7";

    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {
      final myLatlng = LatLng(25.373327, 55.399455);

      // another location
      final myLatlng2 = LatLng(1.4521, 103.9198);

      final mapOptions = MapOptions()
        ..zoom = 14.4746
        ..center = LatLng(25.373327, 55.399455);


      final elem = DivElement()
        ..id = htmlId
        ..style.width = "100%"
        ..style.height = "100%"
        ..style.border = 'none';


      final map = GMap(elem, mapOptions);

      final marker = Marker(MarkerOptions()
        ..position = myLatlng
        ..map = map
        ..title = 'Hello World!'
        ..label = 'h'
        ..icon =
            'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png');

      // Another marker
      Marker(
        MarkerOptions()
          ..position = myLatlng2
          ..map = map,
      );

      final infoWindow =
          InfoWindow(InfoWindowOptions()..content = contentString);
      marker.onClick.listen((event) => infoWindow.open(map, marker));
      return elem;
    });

    return HtmlElementView(viewType: htmlId);
  }
}

var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
    '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
    'Heritage Site.</p>' +
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

and this is the log :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Mi 9 SE in debug mode...

Compiler message:
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.dart:19:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' show Node, Document;
       ^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js_wrapping-0.5.0/lib/js_wrapping.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
       ^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js_wrapping-0.5.0/lib/js_wrapping.dart:11:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js';
^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js_wrapping-0.5.0/lib/adapter/js_list.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
       ^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js_wrapping-0.5.0/lib/adapter/js_map.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
       ^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.dart:203:45: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
    with MapMixin<ControlPosition, MVCArray<Node>> {
                                            ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.dart:207:12: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  MVCArray<Node> operator [](covariant ControlPosition key) {
           ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.dart:214:51: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  void operator []=(ControlPosition key, MVCArray<Node> value) {
                                                  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.dart:226:12: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  MVCArray<Node> remove(Object key) {
           ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/data/data_geometry_collection.dart:39:35: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  _DataGeometryCollection.created(JsObject o) : super.created(o);
                                  ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/data/data_multi_line_string.dart:39:32: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  _DataMultiLineString.created(JsObject o) : super.created(o);
                               ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/data/data_multi_polygon.dart:43:29: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  _DataMultiPolygon.created(JsObject o) : super.created(o);
                            ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/data/data_polygon.dart:37:24: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  _DataPolygon.created(JsObject o) : super.created(o);
                       ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map/map.dart:19:17: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  factory _GMap(Node mapDiv, [MapOptions opts]) => null;
                ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map/map.dart:28:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node get div => _getDiv();
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map/map.dart:29:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node _getDiv();
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/image_map_type.dart:23:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/image_map_type.dart:23:44: Error: Type 'Document' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
                                           ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/image_map_type.dart:24:20: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  void releaseTile(Node tile);
                   ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/map_type.dart:21:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/map_type.dart:21:44: Error: Type 'Document' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
                                           ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/map_type.dart:22:20: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  void releaseTile(Node tile);
                   ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/styled_map_type.dart:23:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/styled_map_type.dart:23:44: Error: Type 'Document' not found.
  Node Function(Point tileCoord, num zoom, Document ownerDocument) getTile;
                                           ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/map_types/styled_map_type.dart:24:20: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  void releaseTile(Node tile);
                   ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/mvc/mvcarray.dart:29:21: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  _MVCArray.created(JsObject o, [Codec<E, dynamic> codec])
                    ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/overlays/map_panes.dart:21:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node floatPane;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/overlays/map_panes.dart:22:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node mapPane;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/overlays/map_panes.dart:23:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node markerLayer;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/overlays/map_panes.dart:24:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node overlayLayer;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/overlays/map_panes.dart:25:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node overlayMouseTarget;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/save_to_google_maps/save_widget.dart:19:23: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  factory _SaveWidget(Node container, [SaveWidgetOptions opts]) => null;
                      ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/services/directions_renderer.dart:25:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node get panel => _getPanel();
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/services/directions_renderer.dart:26:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node _getPanel();
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/services/directions_renderer.dart:35:13: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  set panel(Node panel) => _setPanel(panel);
            ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/services/directions_renderer.dart:36:18: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  void _setPanel(Node panel);
                 ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/services/directions_renderer_options.dart:27:3: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  Node panel;
  ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/street_view/street_view_panorama.dart:19:31: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  factory _StreetViewPanorama(Node container,
                              ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/core/street_view/street_view_panorama.dart:62:10: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  Stream<JsObject> get onCloseclick => getStream(this, 'closeclick');
         ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.g.dart:11:45: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
    with MapMixin<ControlPosition, MVCArray<Node>> {
                                            ^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.g.dart:13:20: Error: Type 'JsObject' not found.
  Controls.created(JsObject o) : super.created(o);
                   ^^^^^^^^
/F:/Flutter/cod/flutter_windows_v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps-3.4.1/lib/src/google_maps_src.g.dart:16:12: Error: Type 'Node' not found.
  MVCArray<Node> operator [](covariant ControlPosition key) {
           ^^^^
```

Comment: Try upgrading flutter with `flutter upgrade` and also please show the output of `flutter doctor --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

You can load the correct dependency at run-time.
For this example I'd assume you want to show a widget with the correct maps.

We need to create 4 files:

1. mobile.dart
2. web.dart
3. unsupported.dart
4. maps.dart

maps.dart:
This will decide at runtime which file is needed, you must import always this file only.

```
 export 'unsupported.dart'
 if (dart.library.html) 'web.dart'
 if (dart.library.io) 'mobile.dart';
```

In the rest 3 dart files, you can define your class and functions. e.g a function that builds the map

**unsupported.dart:**

```
class MapUtils {

 static Widget buildMap() { 
  //nothing to do here
 }
}
```

**mobile.dart:**

```
class MapUtils {

 static Widget buildMap() { 
  //import the mobile google maps and build the widget
 }

}
```

**web.dart:**

```
class MapUtils {

 static Widget buildMap() { 
   //import the web google maps and build the widget
 }

}
```

Comment: the problem was a long time ago, but I remember that I've tried this solution and also didn't work, don't know if something changed since then.